# event handlers function like onload and onLocationfound are not working function is not being excecuted

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-hooks, react-leaflet

I'm trying to get the current user location with the following code:

```
const OSMap: React.FC = () => {
  const [mapState] = useState({ lat: 51.505, lng: -0.09, zoom: 13 })

  const handleLocationFound = event => {
    console.log('tesr', event.latLng)
  }

  return (
    <Map
      center={[mapState.lat, mapState.lng]}
      onLocationfound={handleLocationFound}
      zoom={mapState.zoom}
    >
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
    </Map>
  )
}
```

handleLocationFound or handleLoad are not being called what am I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not an `onLocationfound` prop you can pass on `Map` component. See [here](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/master/src/Map.js#L41)

I guess what you are trying to achieve is having an onClick event on the map and get the coordinates once you click it. You can achieve that like this:

```
const OSMap: React.FC = () => {
  const [mapState] = useState({ lat: 51.505, lng: -0.09, zoom: 13 })

  const handleLocationFound = event => {
    console.log('tesr', event.latlng)
  }

  return (
    <Map
      center={[mapState.lat, mapState.lng]}
      onClick={handleLocationFound}
      zoom={mapState.zoom}
    >
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
    </Map>
  )
}
```

by replacing `onLocationfound` with `onClick` and `e.latLng` with `e.latlng`

**Edit**: I looked at your example [here](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/master/example/components/events.js) and obviously there is an `onLocationfound` event which confused me as in native leaflet is called `locationFound` and becomes `onLocationFound` in react-leaflet. If you want to achieve sth like in the example it works once the geolocation takes place you receive the event object and to access the coords you need to take `e.latlng` as I mentioned before. Here is a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/event-handlers-function-like-onload-and-onlocationfound-are-not-working-function-is-not-being-executed-lo452) to see it live.

check [here](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#map-locationfound) and [here](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#locationevent-latlng) for the docs

Comment: Thank you for the response! while the onclick works I want to get the coordinates on mapload. So like explained here: https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/en/events I want to use onload but the function is not being called when using: onload={handleLocationFound}

Comment: like this example which doesn't work https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/master/example/components/events.js

Comment: that answer worked for me! It seems that I didn't have the mapRef and  map.leafletElement.locate(); included like I should've done! thank you so much!